# Netlogo, asking a rounded up value of agents to do a task

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to find a function or method in NetLogo where a round-up and rounding-down a value is performed. There are two functions n-of and up-to-n-of, however, both functions perform rounding down (i.e 0.4 will result in 0 and 0.6 will also result in 0). What I wish to do is if I get a value of 0.4 round it down 0 but if I  get a value of 0.6 round it up to 1. This is a huge problem in my model because the values I get are between 0 and 1.

```
ask n-of (0.8 * (count pop-agents with [TS = 3 and Deceased? = False])) (pop-agents with [TS = 3 and 
Deceased? = False]) [
  set deceased? true
]
```

The result get is something of the sort of, ask n-of (0.94) [set Deceased? = True]. So no one ever dies in my model.
Is there an easy way to solve this where rounding up and rounding down are considered together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to do is `round` the value. you can do that in two steps, so:

```
let target-num round (0.8 * (count pop-agents with [TS = 3 and not deceased?]))
ask n-of target-num (pop-agents with [TS = 3 and not deceased?]) [set deceased? true]
```

You can also do it in one step, just by putting the `round` in front of the brackets in your current code.

Also, in NetLogo, you can just do `not deceased?` instead of `deceased? = false`. Finally, I changed all your `Deceased?` to `deceased?` - I don't know which way you have it, but you need to be consistent and your provided code is not.